# Почему не видит переменную с ссылкой на картинку?

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на кнопку add я создаю обьект и вкладываю в него ссылку на картинку, при нажатии на кнопку show создается строчка в таблице и заполняется данными из обьекта. Так вот все данные заполняются, кроме картинки. Что я делаю не так?

**Вот код :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Main</title>

<script src="Car.js"></script>
<script>
    var myCarArray = [];
    function addCar() {
        var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        var price = document.getElementById("inputPrice").value;
        var image = document.getElementById("inputImage").value;

        myCarArray.push(new Car(name, price, image));
    }
    function showCar() {
        var theTable = document.getElementById("showCars");
        for (var x = 0; x < myCarArray.length; x++) {
            myCarArray[x].showMe(theTable);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="10">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><input id="inputName"></th>
    <th><input id="inputPrice"></th>
    <th><input id="inputImage"></th>
</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="addCar()">add</button>
<button onclick="showCar()">show</button>

<table border="10" id="showCars">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Вот класс :**

```
function Car(theName, thePrice, theImage) {
this.name = theName;
this.price = thePrice;
this.image = theImage;
}
Car.prototype.showMe = function (table) {
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var name = row.insertCell(0);
name.innerHTML = this.name;
var price = row.insertCell(1);
price.innerHTML = this.price;
var image = row.insertCell(2);
image.innerHTML = "<img width= '100' src='this.image'/>";
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
image.innerHTML = "<img width= '100' src='this.image'/>";
```

Это не php - интерполирование переменных не происходит. Попробуйте так:

```
image.innerHTML = '<img width="100" src="' + this.image + '" />';
```